# Apache RewriteMap with multiple RewriteCond not working

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I'm using a `RewriteMap` and a rule (using the map) with two `RedirectCond`

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(DE|FR|IT|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(de|it|fr).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ https://${DOMAIN}/${lc:%1}/${lc:%2}/home.html [L,R=302]
```

but it's not working. Should I use `${lc:%1}` or `${lc:$1}` ? As per Apache doc we need to use `$` for `RewriteMap` and `%` for `RewriteCond`.

Comment: What is `${DOMAIN}` ? Also, what do you mean by `not working` ? Do you try it directly inside the apache config file or in a htaccess ? To answer your question, `${lc:%1}` is the right way since `%N` are references for condition matching, while `$N` are references for rule matching

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have 503 Internal error. You should set

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

in your virtual host config (But it's only possible if you have write permissions).
And then try to find what's going wrong in your error log. I don't know certain way to solve your problem but this approach is a good opportunity to debug your rules. And for several cases you can use [this site](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be) for testing your rules. Hope it help.

And yes, you are right. % for RewriteCond, $ for RewriteRule